# How to set font size in dompdf?

Tags: php, css, dompdf

I have a problem with font size in invoice generating using `DomPDF`. The font size is not affected in the generated pdf.

Here's the css code

```
a {
    font-family: 'arial';
    font-size:15;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more info?

Comment: Did you tried with `!important`?

Comment: Hi Sitilge,
<a   style=" display: inline-block; font-size:15;  text-align: right; width: 100%;"> <?php echo "test";?></a>
test is not changing as per the size, its accepted only default size.

Comment: Hi Tajgeer,

Lot of Thanks... Working fine,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be

```
a {
    font-family: 'arial';
    font-size:15px;
}
```

you forgot to add `px` in `font-size`

or as per your comment

```
<a style=" display: inline-block; font-size:15px; text-align: right; width: 100%;"> <?php echo "test";?></a>
```

Comment: HI Rahul,  

<a style=" display: inline-block; font-size:15px; text-align: right; width: 100%;"> <?php echo "test";?></a>

it's not working in DomPdf.

Below code working fine(DomPdf):

<a   style=" display: inline-block;   font-size:30 !important; text-align: right; width: 100%;"> <?php echo "test";?></a>

Comment: well I dont have any experience with dompdf but if its works for you its good then, if you want you can marked my answer as accepted if it helps you